# Layers over some, under others, overlapping?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have three layers in an illustrator artboard: a circle, square and triangle. The three shapes overlap, but i want the triangle to be above the circle, the circle above the square, and the square above the triangle. How would I do this?? Thanks

Image at this link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7shDe.jpg

Comment: Have you tied duplicating the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

Use pathfinder to cut the square out of the triangle. You will need to copy the square above the triangle, select the square (the one above the triangle) and the triangle and use the pathfinder panel to subtract the square from the triangle

[image]

*The second button on the top row is the 'subtract' shape mode, which will cut out the top shape from the bottom shape*